# Outlook 2016 - How do I create a search folder for emails that are sent directly to or CC'd to me?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I don't think in general I can specify a search condition like '{predicate} or {predicate}', so I don't think there is an answer to my question.

In Outlook 2010 the default 'Sent Directly to Me' search folder can find all emails that are either 'To = me' or 'CC = me', <s>but in Outlook 2016 it becomes 'To = me' only, which is annoying.</s>

---

(Edit: 20180726)
There was a problem with my Outlook's ost file or the company's exchange server (I don't know about the details. I asked the IT to investigate after I saw Yiku Sun's answer). Now the default 'Sent Directly to Me' search folder also has both the to me and cc me emails after they fixed it.

Comment: So, are you asking how to create a search folder for emails that are sent directly to or CC’d to *someone*, or for emails that are sent directly to or CC’d to ***you**?*  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested in my Outlook 2016 but cannot reproduce the issue. The search folder can find all messages where I was in either To or CC field.

[image]

Comment: This worked great!  FWIW, If you are using this to wrangle your inbound emails, I strongly recommend only including emails in your inbox, or filter the folders to avoid emails that had been filed away to folders after they've been handled.

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5). It looks like you'll be able to set it up the way you want it, and doesn't look like it takes much time to complete :)

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I was aware of the custom criteria in search folder, but I don't think it lets me to set it up the way I want it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Step 4

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this only creates a folder for emails that are CC'd to me. Yuki Sun's answer is correct.